# is this shape possible with css3

Tags: css

I would like to produce this with pure **css** *or as close as possible*
[image: example 1]

The grey area is not nessicarily needed, I am more interested in the black. 
I know how to make a triangle like this
[image]

But I don't know where to do from there. Is this even possible?

Comment: I think it's possible let's check this link, it will help you http://www.css3shapes.com/

Answer (score 3):

I know you ask for a "pure" CSS shape, but here is what i can help with, and it uses a small HTML  part, as css3 radius dont do negative radius yet

Here is the HTML

```
<div class=" frame1 ">
    <div class=" box "></div>
    <div class=" frame2 "> 
        <div class=" bottoml "></div>
        <div class=" bottomr "></div> 
    </div>  
</div>
```

And here is the CSS

```
.frame1
{ 
width:300px;
height:150px;
background-color:#444;  
}

.box
{ 
width:300px;
height:75px; 
background-color:#ccc; 
}

.frame2
{
width:300px;
height:75px;
}

.bottoml
{ 
float:left; 
width:145px;
height:75px; 
background-color:#fff; 
border-top-right-radius:120px 80px;
}   

.bottomr
{ 
float:right;
width:145px;
height:75px; 
background-color:#fff; 
border-top-left-radius:120px 80px; 
}
```

and the fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/WDgYz/

Answer (score 0):

Producing arbitrary shapes with CSS is indeed possible, and the shape you've drawn in the question should be possible. @pundit's answer already points to the one website http://www.css3shapes.com/ which best demonstrates the possibilities of what can be done with CSS3.

However, please understand that these are hacks. Creating arbitrary shapes using CSS is very clever, but is really not what CSS was intended for. I would council you to avoid being too "clever" when creating a real web site. You'll need to create extra markup in your HTML to support it, which rather defeats the point of CSS.

Importantly, you should also note that a large number of the shapes on the css3shapes website fail to display correctly in some browsers. Obviously IE8 and earlier will struggle with a lot of them, but even browsers like Firefox 3.6 fail to display some of them correctly.

Obviously they all work fine in all of the most up-to-date browsers .... but then all of the most up-to-date browsers also support technologies such as Canvas and SVG, which are much better suited to rendering this kind of shape drawing on the browser than CSS hacks.

Okay, so IE8 doesn't support Canvas or SVG either, but there are at least some tools for older versions of IE which allow it to simulate Canvas and SVG. I  certainly wouldn't want to try to get it working properly for all those CSS shapes.

Comment: the point was actually for a joke. I wanted to make an apple logo with a single div and css + :before, :after and have it display on iOS device... with a big "F U Flash" at the bottom.

Comment: @rlemon - fair enough; I guess if there ever was a good place to use css shapes, then that's probably it!  :)  Curious: Did you manage to achieve an Apple shape in the end? Sounds like a tough one.

Comment: I got close, and am still working on it *as a sunday-morning project*, however I think I may need to use more than a single tag (the stem for the apple is next to impossible without)

Comment: this was stemmed from my other *power of css* example, which can now be seen on my [homepage](http://www.rlemon.com) *this again was a quick project, mainly for a **joke**, but it can be extended for real world applications*

Comment: hehe. nice. I stand by my answer that css shapes isn't the right solution for normal usage, but for stuff like this it is good fun. Would love to see your css apple shape when it's finished.

Comment: I will update when it's done (Friday here, so likely will be done sunday morning... when i get time)